# Retrieve count of data from SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm having a little trouble when trying to come up with the command to count the number of letter "B" in the level "2".

```
_id|letter|level
0   A      1
1   A      1
2   B      1
3   A      2
4   B      2
5   A      2
6   B      2
7   B      2
8   B      2
9   B      2
```

This is the "code" I have so far in my DBAdapter.

```
public long getNumberCorrect() {
        int i = 0;
        String query = "SELECT **NUMBER OF LETTER B** FROM table WHERE level = 2";
        Cursor  cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {

                  }
        }
        return i;

    }
```

Ideally, the code above would return 5, but I don't know what to replace "**NUMBER OF LETTER B**" with though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `count(*)`?

```
Something like:
String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE level = 2 and letter='B'";
Cursor  cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);
if (cursor.getCount() >0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   i = cursor.getInt(1);
}
return i;
```

Comment: Nope, didn't know how to use that command. The (*) was throwing me off. Didn't know whether I insert my variable name in there or what.

Comment: @eghdk you will be able to retrieve the count result using: `cursor.getInt(1)`

Comment: Should I use `AS _lCount` as recomended by @android-developer?

Comment: @eghdk you can but it is not mandatory. You can have your original query and use getInt by id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE level = 2 and letter='B'
```

or you can

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE level = 2 and letter='B'
```

Comment: What's the difference between `*` and `id`.

Comment: * will count all the rows, and id here is the column name which will be unique
In this scenario both will return same count

Answer (score 0):

This is the good request :

```
select count(*) from table where level=2 AND letter like 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

write the below query

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE level = 2 AND letter='B'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
String sqlite = "SELECT count(_id) AS _lCount FROM table WHERE level = 2 and letter='B'";
Cursor  cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);
if(cursor != null){
  if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_lCount"));

  }
}
```

this should do the trick. : )